# can Legendre polynomials take on different forms?

Tags: linear-algebra, legendre-polynomials

My prof. assigned some homework that has us compute legendre polynomials, but I'm getting polynomials that are different from ones that I reference with on like Wolfram and Wikipedia.  I think the inner product given to work with is the issue:  the integrand of factors is f(x)*g(x), where neither one of them is conjugated.

I think typically one of those factors is conjugated.

The set of polynomials I got, after using Gram-Schmidt is certainly an orthogonal set (I checked this).  My question is:  is this set *also* referred to as "legendre" polynomials, even though they're are different from the ones I am finding on reference websites?

Is the only requirement that these polynomials be mutually orthogonal?

Also, what about the magnitude?  We were not asked to normalize any of these polynomials.  Is a set of legendre polynomials necessarily orthonormal, too?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gram-Schmidt process yields different orthonormal sets if the order of the original basis is different. I think Legendre polynomials are only referred to the standard known ones, defined uniquely by the Legendre's differential equation,

$$[(1-x^2) P_n'(x)]' = -n(n+1)P_n(x)$$

with $P_n(1) = 1, n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thanks, @CheungSW.  Have a great night :)